# PDFView unable to move to nextpage

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ios-pdfkit

Code:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "pdf") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            }
        }
```

i try to show pdf file in app.it is working fine.how to implement horizontal scrolling(page by page) and search function(like highlight search word) features.any help will be appericated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add this line of code:

```
pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
```

****UPDATE**

[PDFDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument) . has some notifications about search. Have a look.

Comment: thanks it is working fine.sorry i have not enough reputation to upvote you.any idea on search function?

Comment: what do you mean by search function?

Comment: like move to a specific page or highlight a matching word like word document

Answer (score 0):

try this code for searching string.in this line beginFindString you can set string

```
var searchedString: PDFSelection?
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.document?.beginFindString("StringName", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)        
}

func documentDidEndDocumentFind(_ notification: Notification) {
    pdfView.setCurrentSelection(searchedString, animate: true)
}

func documentDidFindMatch(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let selection = notification.userInfo?.first?.value as? PDFSelection {
        selection.color = .Red
        if searchedString == nil {
            // The first found item sets the object.
            searchedString = selection
        } else {
            // All other found selection will be nested
            searchedString!.add(selection)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is searchedItem here?

Comment: change searchedItem to searchedString

Comment: documentDidEndDocument, documentDidFindMatch method not being called

Comment: pls delegate your pdfview

Comment: need to set pdfview.delegate = self?

Comment: @karthi yes add the delegate  pdfview.delegate = self